# jQuery: How update <span> value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need access this specific span, i have multiples , but what needs update is:

```
<span property="v:votes">20</span>
```

to eg:

```
<span property="v:votes">50</span>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Use an attribute selector - `$('span[property="v:votes"]').text('50');`... or without jQuery - `document.querySelector('span[property="v:votes"]').textContent = '50';`

Comment: can you provide more code ?

Comment: The reason i asked for more code is because if you have multiple spans with property="v:votes", the above solution will replace all the values in the spans (e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/3d04yfcm/). If you are targeting only a specific span, then using an id would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just simply need to do is the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('span[property="v:votes"]').html('abcdy fdsfsf<br>gdgfdg');
});
```

Using `.html()` You can add html tag into it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your span an id:

```
<span id="1234">20</span>
```

You can then reference that span very easily like this:

```
document.getElementById("1234")
```

Then, changing its inner value is a piece of cake:

```
document.getElementById("1234").textContent = "50";
```

I personally think this is the easiest way, without jQuery. If you want to use jQuery, try: `$('#1234').text("50");`